# php limit website used based on session id and/or ip address & account for proxy switchers

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

I really don't think there is a fool-proof method for this but of course I'm coming here for advice...

I have a project that I want to restrict to 3 uses per day per user based on IP address. Of course I can do this easily with a mysql table for traditional use cases...but how would I account for those clever enough to use something like [foxyproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) (a proxy switcher plugin for firefox) and/or open a new browser to get a new session. Every use would appear as a fresh, unique user.

Am I stuck to a non-fool-proof method or is there anything else I can try? I am pretty certain that most of our user base will not have a clue how to use or even what these methods are but I want to account for it anyway.

**EDIT**: If there is a non-php solution to this as well, I am open to any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is literally nothing you can do to prevent this in a `fool-proof` way. No matter what you come up with, working around it will be trivial for anyone with a vague clue about how the web works.

You should implement a proper authentication system and limit based on the user ID instead of the host accessing the service.

Comment: Nothing stopping someone from registering more user IDs either, unless you're doing something like requiring a credit card authorization for access.

Comment: I agree that this is the best approach. I do require my users to enter their email to view results so I could just enforce it based off email address at that point. Good call and many thanks.

Comment: @ceejayoz A very valid point. It's a question of how much you care about the rate-limiting, I guess.

Comment: @ceejayoz is very correct. In my case the user has to enter an email address and then verify it through a link sent to the real email address. While this still isn't fool-proof it would be a huge inconvenience for a user that doesn't have multiple email addresses laying around.

Answer (score 0):

some proxy servers may (or may not) set real ip address in HTTP header like HTTP_CLIENT_IP or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR You can also try to differentiate users based on other variables found in `$_SERVER` like

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_X_DNT_OVERSION] => 2.2.1.611
[HTTP_X_DNT_COHORT] => 2012-8-2
[HTTP_X_DNT_VERSION] => 2.2.8.307 FF ffamo 10008
```

It's not perfect, they all can be forged and you will get a lot of false positives because a lot of people have this settings, but if you are really that desperate it may be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You just can limit it with a cookie and a ip blocking list (of course you can also use flash cookies, javascript's localstorage and so on). In both you save the amount of usings of your services and the times he used it.
If a user just tries to delete his cookies without getting a new ip (be it a proxy or , you set a new cookie (because you can check this based on your ip list). Of course the other way round too (setting cookie if hes just changing his ip).

That works for the most normal users. But there is no way to be absolutely sure that nobody can bypass your limits.

Comment: Cookies and IP blocking list is useless if I have access to a proxy list and can switch it out dynamically. I can't enforce cookies on server-side.

Comment: As discussed in the other answer you can just add more barriers but not completely prevent it.